# FreePBX Queues Issue

Tags: center, asterisk, priority-queue, phone-call

I'm experiencing some issues with FreePBX queueus.
The longest calls waiting don't always seem to have priority, in various cases we've experienced instances when a call was on hold for 10 ten minutes and another call came in and the new call was sent to the next available agent before it.

Anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

According to what I've been told by some developers, this seems to be a bug in Asterisk's queue application. The queue app doesn't seem to share the longest wait times across the queues, thus, if a member is part of multiple queues, there could be some problems like what we've experienced.

I have come to accept that and moved on to a commercial grade Call Center solution.